# Array inside an array(2 dimensional array) convert to string

Tags: php, arrays, string, converters

How does one correctly/properly convert an array like this?

For example, if I do, `print_r($array);`

It would print out a result like,

```
Array([0] => Array([0] => 5))
```

How did that array come to be?

I know how to convert a single array to string by using `implode()`. It however, doesn't work on an array inside an array.

I don't think using `implode()` twice will do the trick. Does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get the array as string, use [print_r](https://www.php.net/print_r) **with the second parameter true**

```
$string  = print_r($array, true);
```

or [serialize](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.serialize.php)

```
$string  = serialize($array);
```

or [json_encode](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.json-encode.php)

```
$string  = json_encode($array);
```

And if you want to use implode, use this with [array_walk_recursive](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php)

```
function test_print($item, $key)
{
    if (is_array($item))
    {
        echo implode(',', $item);
    }
}

array_walk_recursive($array, 'test_print');
```

Comment: The array is an associative array, since its a query from a database,

it has position of the cols, so if i retrieve 2 persons. The first person's data would be overwritten.

How would i do this?

Comment: use array_walk_recursive and decorate your associate array as you like

Answer (score 0):

Why not just loop it using a `foreach` construct ?

Something like this..

```
<?php
$arr = array(0=>array(0=>5),1=>array(0=>6));
foreach($arr as $arr1)
{
$str.=implode(' ',$arr1).",";
}
echo rtrim($str,','); //"prints" 5,6
```